# How to copy a file from a symbian phone to pc using Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, smartphone

I have tried many times to copy the files from my Symbian phone to my Ubuntu PC but it doesn't happen.

Comment: which phone are you talking about and do you have drivers installed and do you have cable with you?

Comment: @Creator i am talking about e72 nokia and i am using it through bluetooth

Comment: go to the bluetooth option then to send files and select the device but don't forget to pair it before doing all this

Comment: i am talking about copying files present in my phone into my pc not the files of pc into the phone

Comment: It is a visa versa connection you can even copy files from phone you have to check your phone manual for  that

Comment: no i have tried that but the output was 'FILE NAME' IS NOT OWNED BY YOU

Comment: This means you have not granted access permission on your phone for your pc to access or you have not given correct pairing code to match

Comment: i have done all those

Comment: i can just operate them but not copy that down to my pc